# How to track down dependencies of a Windows executable?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, linker, exe

I have `Tests.exe` with unit tests. It includes a bunch of static libs from my project to test functionality from them. It also contains some tests for the renderer library, which in turn references several functions from `vulkan-1.dll`. The `Tests.exe` executable however does not call any (rendering) functions that would use Vulkan in any way (it does not even have a window), so I don't understand why the linker keeps references to `vulkan-1.dll` in `Tests.exe`.

Is there a way (some tool) to figure out why the unused references to `vulkan-1.dll` were not removed from `Tests.exe` ?

I already tried using dependency walker, but it only shows me which modules are required for `Tests.exe`, but not why they are required (i.e. which functions from `Tests.exe` reference which functions from which modules).

One more interesting fact, release version of `Tests.exe` does not reference `vulkan-1.dll` at all.

Comment: Link without the `vulkan-1.lib` import library, the linker will tell you not only what externals it couldn't resolve, but also the first function that referenced each.  Probably they will be functions that you never call, but only the optimizing linker was smart enough to cull them (hence the release version doesn't import from this DLL)

Comment: *"The (…) executable however does not call any (rendering) functions that would use Vulkan in any way (it does not even have a window)"* – Just FYI: Vulkan is perfectly fine to use without creating any kind of visible output whatsoever and doesn't need a window.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks that it is a good idea. I did as you said and in the end I realised that I will have to load vulkan dll dynamically, which solves my original issue. So I am not sure if I should close this question or leave it open. My problem is solved, but this question is about a tool to analyse dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

You used Dependency Walker badly. It shows exactly which functions are imported from any required DLL: by default, when you click on a DLL in the top-left treeview, it will be shown in the top-right listview.
The listview just below shows what the DLL exports (full list).

Look here: I've selected `SHELL32.DLL`, it shows that I needed it only for `CommandLineToArgvW` (which also tells me that this program is Unicode, BTW). Since I didn't used it myself, then it's probably something introduced by either Qt's framework or directly by Windows - so no real need to care too much about it.

[image: Screenshot from Dependency Walker]

So now, open again your program with Dependency Walker (the debug version obviously), select `vulkan-1.dll` and see which functions are imported "for real". So you'll have a clue on why the DLL is indeed needed.

Since it happens only in Debug, a guess will be that you need it for either an allocator or similar functionality, or for a checking/assert function that is removed in Release.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did notice this Window, but it is not what I want. I basically wanted to figure out the "probably something introduced by either Qt's framework or directly by Windows" part. In other words, I knew vulkan was a required dependency, but `Tests.exe` did not use it directly anywhere, so it had to come from one of the static libs that `Tests.exe` links to. And specifically I wanted to know if there is any tool to show me the chain of function(s) from `Tests.exe` all the way to some Vulkan dependency, so I can get rid of it.

Comment: @jcxz You didn't pushed the thinking to the maximum. You'll see which function(s) is (are) required through DW, first. Then, what you need is to set a breakpoint in your program (in Debug, so that's easy) to this (these) Vulkan's functions... Once the debugger stop, examine the call stack. You'll see where (and why!) it's called. And as I said, if it's an allocation/assertion problem, you CAN'T get rid of it. At all. Not in Debug.

Comment: @Wisblade: And what do you do about functions that are off the hot path (for example, called only during error-handling)?  Your debugger breakpoint may never be hit.... yet the program won't link without those functions.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure. But first try to get them called. _**IF**_ it doesn't work, and _**ONLY**_ if it doesn't work, _**THEN**_ you search for something else. **There is no need to worry about minor events as long as major ones aren't checked.** Also, having the name of these Vulkan's imported functions could help a lot - again, if they appears only in Debug and not in Release, then they probably are debug allocators and/or assertion code _and it won't be possible to get rid of them_.